# How to host a node.js web server that can handle requests in port with GitHub pages or InfinityFree

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, webserver, hosting, github-pages

I know this question's answer can be easily looked up in google but sadly I didn't get the answer to my question.

I want to know how to host a *node.js* web server that can handle requests in Github Pages.

If it isn't possible in Github Pages, then in any other hosting service (preferably *InfinityFree*).

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Pages is a *static* hosting provider, meaning that it does not provide any way to host server-side logic.

According to InfinityFree's forums, [they do not support any server-side language other than PHP (including Node.js) as of current.](https://forum.infinityfree.net/t/why-not-add-node-js/38543/4)

If you are looking for a free provider that would allow you to run a Node.js program, you can look into [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or serverless platforms such as [Netlify](https://netlify.com) and [Vercel](https://vercel.com). It is worth noting that, being free, all of these providers have their own limitations and requirements.

If you're willing to pay, you can rent a virtual private server from a provider such as Microsoft Azure or Amazon's AWS for a small amount (exact amount dependent on your location), or make use of their serverless offerings.

Comment: I wanted to deploy a web server in node.js, not a node.js app. Can you explain any way to do that in heroku or some other thing.

Comment: A web server is like any other Node.js application, using an HTTP server package such as Express.

Comment: Ok now I understood, Thanks!

Comment: Is it other than node.js or including node.js in Infinity Free?

Comment: @Darkzite My mistake. They only support PHP, but do not support Node.js, as explained in the linked forum post.

Comment: Ah, no problem.